# Using SpecFlow as primary Requirements Management Tool

Tags: bdd, specflow

We are planning to use [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) as our primary requirements tool for a web based project. This application has lot of variations of some common objective forms. These variations are primarily per user country the application serves (Multi-tenancy).

**Q1. Is SpecFlow a good choice for such requirements?**

We already found that the number of fields in each form is quite large and many of these field needs validations. Some on client side and some on availability of data or other server side validations. This is tedious in SpecFlow although not totally impossible. But this is not what SpecFlow is designed for (Behavior Driven and not data centric)

**Q2. Please suggest what best practices should we follow to capture the requirements in SpecFlow** and

**Q3. In which areas we need to use some other tools. (Where SpecFlow is not able to capture requirements well)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow is a .Net implementation of [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/), a [tool](http://lizkeogh.com/2011/03/04/step-away-from-the-tools/) for [behavior driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) also referred to as [specification by example](http://specificationbyexample.com/key_ideas.html). Scenarios are described in Cucumber's [Gherkin language](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin).

Gherkin lets you specify data in tables either inline or as [examples](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines):

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

Examples:
| start | eat | left |
|  12   |  5  |  7   |
|  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

Using tables may help you specify the fields for your forms in an easy to read way.

If this is still unmanagable, another option is to use NUnit which lets you specify multiple [values](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=values&r=2.5.9) and generate the [Combinatorial](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.5.9) set of test cases. If you want combinatorial test cases with a Cucumber library you may want to consider switching to [TickSpec](http://tickspec.codeplex.com) which supports [multiple example tables](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/examples-examples-examples) per scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious reason why you can't use SpecFlow for this. Just take care to write the specs at a suitably high level of abstraction.

If you post an example of what you think is tedious then it may be possible to give some advice.

Comment: One example of tedious is filling up long personal information forms where you need data validation on multiple field like birthdate, identity numbers like passport, postal codes, having multiple person info in same form such as spouse information, some forms have payment information which has to match with data that has come from bank etc. This being a public service office, the forms are filled with staff at counter and efficiency in data entry is the key.

Comment: What about using a factory to generate the data common to many of these? In Ruby we use FactoryGirl, I'm sure there's a .Net equivalent.

Comment: It is not about generating data for this. It is more about writing specs for this app using SpecFlow. Is it the best tool to cover all requirements or should we use something else.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too fuzzy for me give specific advice. Try write out an sample scenario in SpecFlow-style and see how it looks. Post it here and will give advice if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout the companion product 'SpecLog' as a way of visualizing these requirements.